# How i can save the logo image inside figma design to my local machine

Tags: graphics, figma, figma-api

I am building a web site based on Figma design created by a client, now the design contain some images such as the logo which i want to have a local copy of it.. seems when i right click on the image inside the design i do not get any option to download it or copy it.. any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export any object to an image and save it locally.

First, click on the object you want to export.
Then, on the right side scroll all the way down and you should see the export option.

[image]

It will give you the option to select different formats and the size.

[image]

Check if it's the right thing by clicking preview and then click "Export".
It will save the image locally to your device.